# vmrun suspend VMware Player problem

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have been using VMware workstation for some time but recently switched to VMware player 3.0, (largely due to irritating instllation problems for Workstation 6.5.3 under Ubuntu 9.10 x86_64).

With Workstation, I use the vmrun command to shut down all my virtual machines.

Despite downloading the latest version of Vmware-vix (1.8.1), vmrun suspend  generates this error message:

Unable to connect to host
Error: Service type VIX_SERVICEPROVIDER_VMWARE_WORKSTATION

My reading of the documentation seemed to suggest that vmrun shoudl work with Player as well as Workstation. Please could someone help me understand what' I'm missing here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the -T flag on vmrun to indicate that the target is a vmware player?:

```
-T <hostType> (ws|server|server1|fusion|esx|vc|player)
```

I was able to run suspend with:

```
$ vmrun -T player suspend /export/vmware/cmp/cmp.vmx
```

That's with the player version (3.0.0 build-203739) included in VMWare Workstation 7 (on Ubuntu 9.10).